# Composite with the inclusion of a set

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm currently studying some set theory and I am slightly confused of the terminology in this proposition :

-Suppose that a set `A` is infinite, and there is an injection `f : (Positive Integers) -> A`.

-Suppose that we have a bijection `c : {1,...,n} -> A.`

-Then the composite of c^-1 o f o **inc** : `{1,...,m} -> {1,...,n}.`

-I do not understand the **inc** of the line above. The **inc** between which two sets?

Comment: [Inclusion map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion_map). That means $\text{inc} (1)=1$ and so on.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So whenever I composite with an inclusion, should I say 'Take the result and consider it as a function producing the same element but of its parent'

Comment: Yes; assume that $m \le n$. Then $c^{-1} \circ f \circ \text{inc}(m)=c^{-1} \circ f(m)=c^{-1} (a_m)$ where I've named $a_m$ the image in $A$ of $f(m)$. The result makes sense because we have supposed $c : \{ 1,\ldots,n \} \to A$ and thus $c^{-1} : A \to  \{ 1,\ldots,n \}$